# Is there any way to run ember acceptance test case in slow mode?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-qunit, ember-testing

I have written some ember acceptance test cases. The thing is when I visit the URL `http://localhost:4200/tests` and filter module by Acceptance, the test cases are running lightning fast. Even though those were written in `async` `await` function.

I want to put a time delay for each line using ember run loop `run.later` or `run.next`. But that's not the solution.

Is there a way to add `slow mode` somewhere in the top of the application (or) Is there any test helpers which is already present? So I can see test cases running in action.

Comment: Why not just use breakpoints?

Comment: Again breakpoints is to be added wherever required and have to click run each time when we hit the breakpoints.

Comment: You could use the [pause helpers](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-test-helpers/blob/master/API.md#pause-helpers)

Comment: @PatsyIssa Is this the same like debugger ?

Comment: If you are using mirage, server.timing could help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no "slow mode" for Ember testing, but you can use regular JavaScript methods to slow down your tests yourself. For example, below we've created a `wait` method that you can call in between each step of the test.

This question was featured on an [episode of May I Ask a Question](https://youtu.be/dakldJe5zvs)! You can watch the recording to see examples of how to use the code below plus how to use the debugger and `pauseTest`.

This code will wait one second before moving to the next line, anywhere you put `await wait()`:

```js
import { module, test } from 'qunit';
import { visit, currentURL } from '@ember/test-helpers';
import { setupApplicationTest } from 'ember-qunit';
import { click, find } from '@ember/test-helpers';

function wait(timeout = 1000) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, timeout);
  });
}

module('Acceptance | slowdown', function(hooks) {
  setupApplicationTest(hooks);

  test('clicking the button reveals text', async function(assert) {
    await visit('/');
    await wait();
    await click('.test-button-1');
    await wait();
    assert.equal(find('.some-message').innerText, 'first message');
    await click('.test-button-2');
    await wait();
    assert.equal(find('.some-message').innerText, 'second message');
  });
});
```

I also recommend using your browser's debugger to step through code at your own pace. It's really powerful and will probably help you more than slowing down tests, in most cases. `this.pauseTest()` is also very helpful.

There's also the possibility of using a JavaScript generator for some less-cluttered code, but if you use this, your tests won't exit properly, so it's a temporary approach:

```js
import { module, test } from 'qunit';
import { visit, currentURL } from '@ember/test-helpers';
import { setupApplicationTest } from 'ember-qunit';
import { click, find } from '@ember/test-helpers';

function slowTest(message, generatorFunction) {
  test(message, async function(assert) {
    let generator = generatorFunction(assert);

    window.step = window.next = async () => {
      generator.next();
      await this.pauseTest();
    }

    window.finish = () => {
      generator.return();
      this.resumeTest();
    }

    await this.pauseTest();
  });

}

module('Acceptance | slowdown', function(hooks) {
  setupApplicationTest(hooks);

  slowTest('clicking the button reveals text', function*(assert) {
    yield visit('/');
    yield click('.test-button-1');

    assert.equal(find('.some-message').innerText, 'first message');

    yield click('.test-button-2');

    assert.equal(find('.some-message').innerText, 'second message');
  });
});
```